# Laravel breeze wtih react plus spatie roles and permissions

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

As per the subject.

I am playing around with Laravel Breeze (intertia / React), and trying to add the Spatie roles and permissions package to it.

Followed the docs to spin up my laravel docker container, using sail up - no problem.

Followed the docs to set up breeze scaffolding with inertia / React - again, beautiful, works as a charm.

However, after installing the Spatie permission package (following this: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/installation-laravel) I can no longer access my localhost, or localhost/login etc etc. Nothing in the log I can see thus far

Set up factories, seeding etc, all worked - just when trying to access the app in the browser it gives a "connection refused" error.

I presume it'll be something to do with some routes getting messed up? Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running `php artisan cache:clear` and `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: thanks, that was basically it, it was a cache issue